# shopping cart Spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement this shopping cart example from this link http://o7planning.org/en/10605/create-a-java-shopping-cart-web-application-using-spring-mvc-and-hibernate

I have used the same code as it is.But i am getting the following error.

> WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDBAuthenticationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.AccountDAO org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.authentication.MyDBAuthenticationService.accountDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory** org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.impl.AccountDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
>   May 07, 2017 12:31:59 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
>   SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDBAuthenticationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.AccountDAO org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.authentication.MyDBAuthenticationService.accountDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.impl.AccountDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**Could anyone help me solving this?**

Comment: In the stacktrace you'll find "NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;" This seems like a classloader issue to me

Comment: I am using the same version of hibernate jars in pom.xml as given in the example,Could you please explain how to solve the classloader issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change Hibernate version, using newest hibernate (pom.xml):

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Getting the same error after using newest hibernate, even author in that examle has strictly asked not to use hibernate 5

Comment: I used it with newest Hibernate 5, It worked fine!! Please try it!!

Answer (score 0):

Hie

The problem is within the ApplicationContextConfig.java class.That class contains the following imports

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
```

If you want to keep the project structure as it is change those imports to

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
```

**Note** that I changed hibernate5 to hibernate4 to match with the dependence version in the pom.xml

That should be an alternative solution.

If it helps I would like to hear from.

Thanks regards